# Python: How to refer to optional variables without error

Tags: python, variables, plot, legend, option-type

I am trying to create a legend for a plot with variable sets of data. There are at least 2, and at most 5. The first two will always be there, but the other three are optional, so how can I create a legend for only the existing number of data sets?

I've tried if-statements to tell python what to do if that variable doesn't exist, but without avail. Perhaps this is not the proper way to determine variable existence.

```
line1 = os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(selectedFiles[0])[0]))
line2 = os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(selectedFiles[1])[0]))

if selectedFiles[2] in locals:
    line3 = os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(selectedFiles[2])[0]))
else: line3 = None

if selectedFiles[3] in locals:
    line4 = os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(selectedFiles[3])[0]))
else: line4 = None

if selectedFiles[4] in locals:
    line5 = os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(selectedFiles[4])[0]))
else:line5 = None

legend((line1, line2, line3, line4, line5), loc='upper left')
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
     if selectedFiles[2] in locals:
IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

It is possible that there are multiple issues with his code (not sure if the "None" is the right way to handle the non-existent data). Please bear in mind that I'm am new to python with little programming experience otherwise, so bear with me and try not to condescend, as some more experienced users tend to do.

Comment: How are you creating `selectedFiles`?

Comment: The answers generally have the right idea, but I am curious how `locals` is defined. `locals()` is a built in function that returns the local symbol table, a dictionary mapping variable names to their associated objects. `in locals` will raise an exception if you haven't rebound the name locally, because the `in` operator doesn't work on functions. `in locals()` is syntactically correct but not what you want when you're checking for the existence of elements of an array. Unless your array contains strings that are local variable names.

Comment: So far I'm glad to see that my question was at least partially comprehensible. @thefourtheye selectedFiles is created using a dialog window from Tkinter: 'selectedFiles = tkFileDialog.askopenfilenames(parent=rt,title='Choose a file')
selectedFiles = rt.tk.splitlist(selectedFiles)'

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper, I now understand that I've used 'locals' wrong in two ways. The answers below are close to what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because selectedFiles is a tuple, and the logic of processing each item inside it is same. you can iterate it with a for loop.

```
lines = [os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])) for filename in selectedFiles]

#extend lines' length to 5 and fill the space with None
lines = lines + [None] * (5-len(lines))

legend(lines,loc='upper left')
```

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Why? the first arg of legend() is a iterable object  according to the sample codes.

Comment: I removed the second definition for lines, because then it gives me 3 "nones" on the legend. Otherwise this is perfect!

Answer (score 2):

I have no idea what your data structures look like, but it looks like you just want

```
lines = (os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(x)[0])) for x in selectedFiles)

legend(lines, loc='upper left')
```

Comment: Beat me to it. See in particular http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists for documentation on what's going on with `*lines`. But the parens are balanced differently than the OP's version, so while the approach is correct the precise syntax is probably off.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper noted.  I have recalibrated the balance on my parenthification.

Comment: There's no need for the '*' before 'lines'. That confuses the legend into thinking I want one of the file titles as a location.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer this way.

```
line = []

for i in range(5):
  if i < len(selectedFiles):
    line.append(os.path.basename(str(os.path.splitext(selectedFiles[i])[0])))
  else:
    line.append(None)

legend(tuple(line), loc='upper left')
```

or you can always use `except IndexError:`.

Comment: Just for code golf purposes, if I needed to pad the tuple with `None` and didn't want to use glasslion's solution: `tuple(itertools.islice(itertools.chain(os.path.basename(...) for x in selectedFiles, itertools.repeat(None)), 5))`